# fix file permission to read write access squid configuration via php code in linux server centos with lamp setup

Tags: linux, lamp, squid

For my new project i have to configure cent os linux server with lamp setup and install squid proxy server. Installed machine will act as a server in client side. The main purpose of the count the amount of bandwidth, their mac address , ip address will be logged in server it is will act like a proxy server. Every user will be assigned with bandwidth, total browsing hours, username, password etc.

Each user can access INTERNET via installed proxy server after logging with the username and password defined to them.
User management, mac address, ip addreess fetching all will be done using php code with linux command enabled for mac address from client machine and also for blacklist website filter.

For every action of this project have to access squid configuration file located in /etc/squid/squid.conf for enabling internet support with mac filter and even iptables.

But when my php code try to access the /etc/squid/squid.conf for processing . It is unable to access the file for read, write, append operation.

In my server side i have define the file permission for /etc/squid/squid.conf with read write access with the code executing in my linux  server

```
chmod 777 /etc/squid/squid.conf
```

After assign the permission also the person logged in to the server unable to access the squid file for processing.

Even the tried

```
chmod 666 /etc/squid/squid.conf
```

but no help

How i have to configure my file permission for /etc/squid/squid.conf so even my i logged user via apache server can access the file for processing

Answer (score 0):

is selinux running ? you can temporary disable it with

```
setenforce 0
```

selinux may block apache to read your squid config as they are in 2 differents context even if the file is 777 and apache was running as root(bad ideal) . Here some redhat documentation about squid and selinux [doc](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Managing_Confined_Services/chap-Managing_Confined_Services-Squid_Caching_Proxy.html)

Comment: i cannot disable file permission . it it must.

Comment: i am using centos. i have to enable universal file permission for squid.conf file

Comment: Centos is a copy without brand of redhat. If you want your apache process to access squid config file. You have 2 choices : disable selinux or configure selinux to let apache acess your squid directory(more difficult). You can check /var/log/audit/audit.log for selinux blocking apache to acess squid.conf

Comment: thanks for the support. i will check it. i need the steps to configure apache to access squid file in centos linux.